# Drawing control from Control.Controls in C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, controls

Good day. How to add user control to another user control without using the Control.Controls property? For example, draw a Button on the MyControl : Control object, that the events of button be available? I want to create MyControl that contains another controls, but the Control.Controls collection must be empty, as in all standard WinForms controls.

Comment: I am curious as to reason behind the requirement of not placing controls in Control.Controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add control to `MyControl`, it will be something like

```
this.Controls.Add(control);
```

otherwise control is not displayed. So you **can not** avoid this.

What is the problem to have controls in `Controls` ? *Standard* controls are not composed from other controls (there are exceptions though: `DataGridView` in edit mode and `PropertyGrid`, maybe more).

However you can use dirty tricks, like:

- add control to a parent, wiring up necessary events to `MyControl`;
- mimic control (to example, `Label`, by outputting text in `OnPaint` event).

Wouldn't it be much easier to fight with that what has problem with `Controls` (if there is actually any problem) ?